# Save configuration of buffers, buffer positions and windows for later recall

Tags: buffers, window

I have different workflows with emacs: for example Python development and LaTeX. When I code some Python I like to have a wider window to have different buffers opened at the same time, plus a repl buffer. However when I write LaTeX I prefer having a smaller window with a single buffer, so that I can see the output in Preview.app

So my question is the following. Let's say I switch from coding python to writing LaTeX, is there any way I can save the current state of the whole thing (window width, buffer positions, buffers, etc.) so that when I'm done with LaTeX I can go back quickly to my previous emacs environment?

Thanks !

Comment: See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsAndRegisters  See also elscreen:  http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Elscreen  See also **Switching between window layouts**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2710/switching-between-window-layouts

Comment: And if you want to *persistently* save configurations such as those that @lawlist mentioned, then you can use bookmarks or desktops (or bookmarks to desktops).