# Sensible stack-like quit-restore behavior in side-window?

Tags: window, window-splitting, selected-window

How can I get sensible stack-like behavior from a bottom side-window? I've configured both Ag and Help to display their buffers using `display-buffer-in-side-window`. I like to maintain a window configuration like

```
+-----------+    +-----------+
|           |    |           |
|           |    |     A     | <- main workspace
|     A     | OR |           |
|           |    +-----------+
|           |    |     B     | <- search/compilation/help
+-----------+    +-----------+
```

where **A** is my main work area, and **B** is acts as a drawer for things like search results, compilation errors, and Help buffers. In most cases, I'd like hitting `q` in **B** to bury the buffer and delete the window. If **B** was displaying something else prior, I'd like `q` to bury the current buffer and reveal the previous buffer. Once I've `q`'d out of all the buffers that were displayed in **B** since it popped up, I'd like the window to be deleted. The buffer in **A** should *not* be part of this buffer stack.

For instance, say I start with `my_code.rb` in **A**. I run a search and Ag pops up **B** to display the results. Hitting `q` buries the Ag buffer and deletes **B**, leaving me with a clean view.

But say instead of `q`'ing out of the search results, I ran a help command like describe-variable. A *Help* buffer supplants the search results in **B**. Hitting `q` buries *Help* and the search results are visible again. I hit `q` again, expecting it to bury the search results and delete **B**, but instead it displays `my_code.rb` in **B**, leaving me with an unwanted split view.

It sounds like the `quit-restore` window-parameter controls this, but I'm not sure how to manage it. I inspected its value using at various points during the above flow, and found the following:

search results displayed in **B**:

```
(window
window
#<window A on my_code.rb>
#<buffer *ag search text:my-search-term dir:~/my/path/*>)
```

help buffer displayed in **B**:

```
(other
(#<buffer *ag search text:my-search-term dir:~/my/path/*> 225
 #<marker (moves after insertion) at 225 in *ag search text:my-search-term dir:~/my/path/*> 12)
#<window 72 on *ag search text:my-search-term dir:~/my/path/*>
#<buffer *Help*>)
```

search results again displayed in **B** after quitting the Help buffer:

```
nil
```

So it seems that quitting the Help buffer is causing the `quit-restore` window parameter to be discarded wholesale?

For reference, this is my `display-buffer-alist` configuration:

```
(setq
 display-buffer-alist
 `((,(rx bos
         (or (and "*ag " (1+ not-newline) "*")
             "*Help*")
         eos)
     (display-buffer-reuse-window
      display-buffer-in-side-window)
     (side . bottom))))
```

Comment: Basically, you want to save the window configuration, then do your thing (whatever that may be) and restore your window configuration with something like the letter `q`, which behaves differently than `quit-restore`.  Here is a link to a semi-related thread where I and the original poster (in that thread) wrote up a couple of ways to restore the window configuration after using a `*Help*` buffer:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24031/how-to-display-a-help-buffer-window-full-frame-size-not-full-screen  It should put you on the right track, but may entail some time to customize.