# How to keep a high-level window configuration?

Tags: window, frames, window-splitting

I use Emacs as a single `maximized` frame. The monitor is wide enough for two windows to sit together there, with a vertical split. I want this window configuration to be *permanent*, i.e.:

1. I want it to be impossible to delete either of the two child windows (except for by my explicit request or something) and
2. I want it to be impossible to split the root window (i.e., add another child, in addition to the existing 2).

IOW, I want it to be impossible to change (add or remove) children of the root window.

How do I do that?

Comment: This is not an answer, but would the functions window-configuration-to-register 'C-x r w' and jump-to-register 'C-x r j' be of any use?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2710/17548 speaking about layout. more about registering  and related packages ( not directly answering but a good resource)

Comment: Inasmuch as my workflow remains basically the same through the years, I have created functions that generate certain buffers without displaying them.  Then, I either display them in a specific way all of the time, or assign them to my own custom display buffer function:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  For example, let us take the popular opening of a shell or eshell buffer -- we create the buffer without displaying and then display however we want subsequent to creation:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287